# How can I use jq to sort by datetime field and filter based on attribute?

Tags: jq

I am trying to sort following json response based on "startTime" and also want to filter based on "name" and fetch only "dataCenter" of matched record. Can you please help with jq function for doing it?
I tried something like this `jq '.[]|= sort_by(.startTime)'`  but it doesnt return correct result.

```
[
   {
      "name": "JPCSKELT",
      "dataCenter": "mvsADM",
      "orderId": "G9HC8",
      "scheduleTable": "FD33515",
      "nodeGroup": null,
      "controlmApp": "P/C-DEVELOPMENT-LRSP",
      "groupName": "SCMTEST",
      "assignmentGroup": "HOST_CONFIG_MGMT",
      "owner": "PC00000",
      "description": null,
      "startTime": "2021-11-11 17:45:48.0",
      "endTime": "2021-11-11 17:45:51.0",
      "successCount": 1,
      "failureCount": 0,
      "dailyRunCount": 0,
      "scriptName": "JPCSKELT"
   },
   {
      "name": "JPCSKELT",
      "dataCenter": "mvsADM",
      "orderId": "FWX98",
      "scheduleTable": "JPCS1005",
      "nodeGroup": null,
      "controlmApp": "P/C-DEVELOPMENT-LRSP",
      "groupName": "SCMTEST",
      "assignmentGroup": "HOST_CONFIG_MGMT",
      "owner": "PC00000",
      "description": null,
      "startTime": "2021-07-13 10:49:47.0",
      "endTime": "2021-07-13 10:49:49.0",
      "successCount": 1,
      "failureCount": 0,
      "dailyRunCount": 0,
      "scriptName": "JPCSKELT"
   },
   {
      "name": "JPCSKELT",
      "dataCenter": "mvsADM",
      "orderId": "FWX98",
      "scheduleTable": "JPCS1005",
      "nodeGroup": null,
      "controlmApp": "P/C-DEVELOPMENT-LRSP",
      "groupName": "SCMTEST",
      "assignmentGroup": "HOST_CONFIG_MGMT",
      "owner": "PC00000",
      "description": null,
      "startTime": "2021-10-13 10:49:47.0",
      "endTime": "2021-10-13 10:49:49.0",
      "successCount": 1,
      "failureCount": 0,
      "dailyRunCount": 0,
      "scriptName": "JPCSKELT"
   }
]
```

Comment: Welcome. When you say that you _want to filter based on "name"_ what do you mean exactly? The values of each of the names in the sample JSON are the same, and you haven't mentioned how you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression to sort the input -

```
sort_by(.startTime | sub("(?<time>.*)\\..*"; "\(.time)") | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | mktime)
```

The `sub("(?<time>.*)\\..*"; "\(.time)")` expression removes the trailing decimal fraction.

I assume you can use the result from the above query to perform desired filtering.

Comment: Why not just `sort_by(.startTime)`? WIth this date format string odrering should just work fine.

Comment: Wouldn't that be string based sorting?

Comment: Sure. The point is that with the date format employed here (sequenced in fixed field widths from the most significant to the least significant part, i.e. years to seconds), a string ordering (on the formatted date) would yield the same order as a number ordering (when converted to seconds). More so, if you just cut off fractions from seconds (instead of e.g. going further down to measuring full milliseconds), you may end up with an indeterminate ordering of elements timestamped differently but within the same second.

Comment: Fair point. The author can choose either of the implementations based on his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. From what I'm [guessing you're asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887277/how-can-i-use-jq-to-sort-by-datetime-field-and-filter-based-on-attribute#comment128741596_72887277), you want to supply a value to filter the records on using the `name` property, sort the results by the `startTime` property and then just output the value of the `dataCenter` property for those records. How about this:

```bash
jq --arg name JPCSKELT '
map(select(.name==$name))|sort_by(.startTime)[].dataCenter
' data.json
```

Based on your sample data, this produces:

```
"mvsADM"
"mvsADM"
"mvsADM"
```

So I'm wondering if this is what you're really asking?